# How to filter data in mule- anypoint studio

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I get this response from the magento-connctor get-product operation:

```
{"product_id":"33","sku":"TEST","set":"18","type":"bundle","categories":["2","4","5","16","17","222"],"website["1","3","5","16"],"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"type_id":null,"name":"test","description":null,"short_description":"test description","weight":null,"status":null,"url_key":null,"url_path":null,"visibility":null,"category_ids":null,"website_ids":null,"has_options":null,"gift_message_available":null,"price":null,"special_price":null,"special_from_date":null,"special_to_date":null,"tax_class_id":null,"tier_price":null,"meta_title":null,"meta_keyword":null,"meta_description":null,"custom_design":null,"custom_layout_update":null,"options_container":null,"additional_attributes":[{"key":"highlights","value":"testing Highlights"},{"key":"test_details","value":null},{"key":"frequently_asked_questions","value":"test_faq"}],"enable_googlecheckout":null}
```

How can I filter by attribute and remove some of the data from the payload?

Comment: Your json is broken in the element "categories", I  have corrected it to "categories":["2","4","5","16","17","222"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Dataweave** (Transform Message component in Anypoint Studio), take a look to the documentation:

> https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/using-dataweave-in-studio

A sample script with your data:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    product_id: payload.product_id,
    sku: payload.sku,
    set: payload.set,
    type: payload.type,
    categories: payload.categories map ((category , indexOfCategory) -> category),
    website: payload.website map ((website , indexOfWebsite) -> website),
    created_at: payload.created_at
}
```

Comment: i am getting this error:"No serializer found for class com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )"?

Comment: What element do you have after your transformation?

Comment: ya, it was the issue of element after transformation, thanks works like a charm! +1!