# How to filter data payload in mule CE

Tags: filter, mule, dataweave

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34549817/how-to-filter-data-in-mule-anypoint-studio) was to use `dataweave` but that doesn't support CE version, so how to filter data payload in CE?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating a Java class that takes takes in the payload and outputs it in the format that you'd like.  If you want it to stay JSON as shown in the example, you can return it as JSON (from the class itself) or as a POJO and then convert it to JSON using the Object to JSON transformer.

More info here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.5/java-transformer-reference

Hope that helps,
Mike